# Laravel complexe relationships

Tags: laravel, relationship

I need help please, to figure out for convenient ways to link between User/Staff/Parent/Student.
A Staff/Parent/Student is a user.
A Staff can be a Parent too. Similarly, a Parent may be a Staff too.
A student belongsToMany Parent, and a Parent belongsToMany Student.
Here are the models I've created :

```js
App\Models\Student.php 
  protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'student_user_id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];
    
  public function student_user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'student_user_id');
    }

    public function guardians()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(StudentGuardian::class);
    }
    
==========================================================    
App\Models\StudentGuardian.php
  protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'guardian_user_id',
        'is_staff',
        'guardian_staff_id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];
    
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class);
    }

    public function guardian_user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'guardian_user_id');
    }

    public function guardian_staff()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Staff::class, 'guardian_staff_id');
    }

=====================================
App\Models\Staff.php
  protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'staff_user_id',
        'staff_guardian_id',
        'is_student_guardian',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];
    
    public function staff_user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'staff_user_id');
    }

    public function staff_guardian()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(StudentGuardian::class, 'staff_guardian_id');
    }
```

In the StudentsController, I don't know how to call the students related to the authenticated user

Answer (score 0):

you can use polymorphic relation to handle it.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I've just trying to use your advise, in the Student Model, I've added a function : `public function children()  { return $this->morphTo(); }` and in both the StudentGuardian and User I've added this function `public function my_children() { return $this->morphMany(Student::class, 'children'); } `. But I still fail displaying the children of the authenticated user.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).